# Gmail-like Sign out

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I have a Gmail-like Signout mechanism, such that when you hover on the username (on the top right), it slides down a menu that includes a "sign out" link. The username is on a floated list, while the menu that slides out is on an inner list (not floated). The sliding out/in is performed using jQuery.

This is what it's supposed to do:

- The inner menu slides down (becomes visible) when username is hovered on;
- if the mouse goes to the inner menu, the inner menu should remain visible;
- if the mouse hovers elsewhere, the inner menu should slide back up (becomes invisible).

This is what it currently does:

- The inner menu slides down when the username is hovered on;
- when the cursor is off the username, the menu slides up - regardless of where the cursor is.

Perceived solution: I believe there should be an `if` clause somewhere that checks if the cursor is on the inner list and keep the inner list open, and that's the part that gets me stumped.

**EDIT:** Here is the current code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="user_spot">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="username">username</a>
        <ul id="user_spot_links">
            <li><a href="/home/sign?out=y">Sign Out</a></li> <br />
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
ul#user_spot li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
ul#user_spot_links {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    display:none;
}
ul#user_spot_links li {
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
```

**JS:**

```js
$('ul#user_spot li a').hover(function() {
$('ul#user_spot_links').slideDown('slow');
    return false;
}, function() {
    // this is where I believe the needed code should be"
    $('ul#user_spot_links').slideUp('slow'); 
});
```

Comment: Do you want us to write you a script? I don't think that's the point of stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site.

Comment: Can you include some code in your question? Please show us your current solution and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I don't need anyone to write me a script. I need to understand how to write the script myself; I just need help processing the logic. Current code coming up in a second

Comment: Consider using the [built-in syntax highlighting mechanisms](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) when posting code snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need JS for that.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PaKnc/

Basically the UL that slides down is a child of the LI you hover over. You can manipulate the CSS properties of a child in CSS.

For example:

```
#parent #child {
   style1;
}

#parent:hover #child {
   style2;
}
```

Here, `style1` and `style2` can be totally different. In our case we take advantage of this by altering the `display` property.

Comment: Thanks for that. That resolved the issue. I still have to use JS for it because I like the animation effect. But you've certainly pointed me in the right direction, and I can fix it now. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this updated fiddle for some animation for your menu using CSS transitions alone. http://jsfiddle.net/PaKnc/1/ [NOTE: this will NOT work in IE] :)

Comment: Nice...I like that also. However, I'll still go with the Jquery version, since many features on the site depend on JS anyway. But thanks for the codes; they really help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you need to exit the username anchor to hover over the dropdown.  The simple solution is to just change the hover selector to be the `li` instead of the `a`.  Then, you will not exit it even while you remain hovered over the dropdown.